# OpenTSDB - Return list of metrics using wildcard via http

Tags: opentsdb

Is it possible to return a list of metrics using a wildcard?

e.g. metric=Level1.level2.*

Returns all Level3 metrics for the Level1.Level2 (just how the metrics are structured)

Result would be similar to returning all metrics like so:

```
http://localhost:4242/api/suggest?type=metrics&q=sys&max=1000000
```

Then filtering on the results for a certain string, but it would be great if there was a solution provided by the api?

cheers